# How to check is timer enabled/disabled?

Tags: c#, if-statement, timer

I tried the below but it won't work for me.

```
if (MyTimer.Enabled)
{
    continue;
}
else 
{
    break;
}
```

I want to break the `for` loop if the timer is over.

Comment: What's `MyTimer` BTW?

Comment: Did You set Enabled to true ? This property is not about if Timer is running. MSDN says "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the Timer should raise the Elapsed event." and default is false

Comment: i think `MyTimer` is `System.Timers.Timer` , you can use `OnTimedEvent`, which is fired when timer Elapsed.

Comment: elaborate what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

you can break your loop as written below. The while loop will break as soon as the timer time elapsed.

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer MyTimer;
    static bool runningloop;
    public static void Main()
    {
        runningloop=true;
        MyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = 2000;
        MyTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        MyTimer.Enabled = true;

        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection
        // from occurring before the method ends. 
        //GC.KeepAlive(MyTimer) 

        while(runningloop)
        {
          //do your work here
        }
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        runningloop=false;
    }
```

Reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.100).aspx)